# Copy down last value over a daily period

Tags: r, xts

I have a multi-day XTS object, and I am trying to create an indicator that once true, remains true for the rest of the day. The approach I am trying (but its not working) is combining the na.locf function with the apply daily:

```
output <- apply.daily(x, na.locf)
```

Reproducible code:

```
y <- as.xts(c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),as.POSIXct(c(
                                   "2010-01-05 00:00:00", "2010-01-05 00:04:00", "2010-01-05 00:08:00", 
                                   "2010-01-05 00:12:00", "2010-01-05 00:16:00", "2010-01-05 00:20:00",
                                   "2010-01-06 00:00:00", "2010-01-06 00:04:00", "2010-01-06 00:08:00")))
```

Desired output is to copy down the '1' for the rest of that day. so:

```
y <- as.xts(c(NA,NA,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA),as.POSIXct(c(
                                   "2010-01-05 00:00:00", "2010-01-05 00:04:00", "2010-01-05 00:08:00", 
                                   "2010-01-05 00:12:00", "2010-01-05 00:16:00", "2010-01-05 00:20:00",
                                   "2010-01-06 00:00:00", "2010-01-06 00:04:00", "2010-01-06 00:08:00")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is

```
y1 <- ave(y, as.Date(index(y)), FUN= function(x) na.locf(x, na.rm=FALSE))
y1
#                      [,1]
#2010-01-05 00:00:00   NA
#2010-01-05 00:04:00   NA
#2010-01-05 00:08:00    1
#2010-01-05 00:12:00    1
#2010-01-05 00:16:00    1
#2010-01-05 00:20:00    1
#2010-01-06 00:00:00   NA
#2010-01-06 00:04:00   NA
#2010-01-06 00:08:00   NA

str(y1)
# An ‘xts’ object on 2010-01-05/2010-01-06 00:08:00 containing:
#  Data: num [1:9, 1] NA NA 1 1 1 1 NA NA NA
#  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
#  Original class: 'double'  
# xts Attributes:  
# NULL

str(y)
#An ‘xts’ object on 2010-01-05/2010-01-06 00:08:00 containing:
#  Data: num [1:9, 1] NA NA 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
#  Original class: 'double'  
#  xts Attributes:  
# NULL
```

Comment: This works great. Are you using the ave function just to subset? Or is there another reason?

Comment: @EdWilson The `ave` function is used to apply the `na.locf` on each  'Date'

Answer (score 2):

I think `period.apply` called by `apply.daily` does not like the value returned by `na.locf`. Haven't investigated very thoroughly why. Anyway, I tried to do what it should be doing in a round-about manner. I can see that akrun's answer is definitely superior than this. Just leaving this here.

```
R> y <- as.xts(c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
+             as.POSIXct(c("2010-01-05 00:00:00", "2010-01-05 00:04:00",
+                          "2010-01-05 00:08:00", "2010-01-05 00:12:00",
+                          "2010-01-05 00:16:00", "2010-01-05 00:20:00",
+                          "2010-01-06 00:00:00", "2010-01-06 00:04:00",
+                          "2010-01-06 00:08:00")))
R> endpoints(y, "days")
[1] 0 6 9
R> ep <- endpoints(y, "days")
R> diff(ep)
[1] 6 3
R> dep <- diff(ep)
R> rep.int(1:length(dep), times=dep)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
R> runs <- rep.int(1:length(dep), times=dep)
R> lapply(split(y, runs), na.locf, na.rm=FALSE)
$`1`

2010-01-05 00:00:00 NA
2010-01-05 00:04:00 NA
2010-01-05 00:08:00  1
2010-01-05 00:12:00  1
2010-01-05 00:16:00  1
2010-01-05 00:20:00  1

$`2`

2010-01-06 00:00:00 NA
2010-01-06 00:04:00 NA
2010-01-06 00:08:00 NA

R> splits <- lapply(split(y, runs), na.locf, na.rm=FALSE)
R> do.call('rbind', splits)

2010-01-05 00:00:00 NA
2010-01-05 00:04:00 NA
2010-01-05 00:08:00  1
2010-01-05 00:12:00  1
2010-01-05 00:16:00  1
2010-01-05 00:20:00  1
2010-01-06 00:00:00 NA
2010-01-06 00:04:00 NA
2010-01-06 00:08:00 NA
R> ynew <- do.call('rbind', splits)
```

Comment: This approach is sound and a typical `xts` approach.  Although could achieve the full results just using `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(y, "days"), na.locf))`