# Back-fill vector to last NA on an hourly basis

Tags: r, xts

I have an XTS object with 10 min daily data. An `NA` represents that the rest of that hour's data is invalid. I then need to "back fill" the invalid data with the first data point (9 in the example) of the next hour.

Example:

```
    y <- as.xts(c(3,4,NA,8,5,4,9,5,8),as.POSIXct(c("2010-01-05 08:00", "2010-01-05 08:10", "2010-01-05 08:20", "2010-01-05 08:30", "2010-01-05 08:40", "2010-01-05 08:50", "2010-01-05 09:00", "2010-01-05 09:10", "2010-01-05 09:20"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

Desired Output:

```
y1 <- as.xts(c(3,4,9,9,9,9,9,5,8),as.POSIXct(c("2010-01-05 08:00", "2010-01-05 08:10", "2010-01-05 08:20", "2010-01-05 08:30", "2010-01-05 08:40", "2010-01-05 08:50", "2010-01-05 09:00", "2010-01-05 09:10", "2010-01-05 09:20"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

I believe I've got half way there using the `ave` function (as suggested as an answer to a similar question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184867/copy-down-last-value-over-a-daily-period))

```
y1 <- ave(y, format(as.POSIXct(index(y),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),"%H"), FUN= ?)
```

which should allow me to apply a function the data factored by the hour, but this is where Im stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#make all values after NA also NA until next hour
y2 <- do.call(c, 
        tapply(y, trunc(index(y), "hours"), 
               FUN = function(x) x * cumprod(NA^is.na(x))))

y2 <- as.xts(na.locf(y1, fromLast = TRUE))
#                    [,1]
#2010-01-05 08:00:00    3
#2010-01-05 08:10:00    4
#2010-01-05 08:20:00    9
#2010-01-05 08:30:00    9
#2010-01-05 08:40:00    9
#2010-01-05 08:50:00    9
#2010-01-05 09:00:00    9
#2010-01-05 09:10:00    5
#2010-01-05 09:20:00    8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
y2 <- ave(y, cumsum(is.na(y)), format(index(y)-1, "%H"), 
           FUN = function(x) if(any(is.na(x))) tail(x,1) else x)
identical(y1, y2)
#[1] TRUE
```

NOTE: No additional packages used :-)