# rbind.zoo(...) : indexes overlap Error

Tags: r, aggregate, xts, zoo

I am trying to apply a function to an xts object. I am using the `ave` function to apply the function to each day separately. The function is throwing the following error:

```
Error in rbind.zoo(...) : indexes overlap In addition: Warning messages:
1: In split.default(seq_len(nrow(xc)), f, drop = drop, ...) :
   data length is not a multiple of split variable
2: In zoo(value2, i2) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I have debugged the function, and its throwing the error when I try and convert `-Inf` to `NA` with the following line: `x[x == -Inf] <- NA`.

Here is a minimum reproducible example applying just the problematic line of the function via the `ave` function:

```
x <- as.xts(c(NA,-Inf,1,2,3,-Inf,NA,NA,NA),as.POSIXct(c(
  "2010-01-05 00:00:00", "2010-01-05 00:04:00", "2010-01-05 00:08:00", 
  "2010-01-05 00:12:00", "2010-01-05 00:16:00", "2010-01-05 00:20:00",
  "2010-01-06 00:00:00", "2010-01-06 00:04:00", "2010-01-06 00:08:00")))

out <- ave(x, as.Date(index(x)), FUN= function(x) x[x == -Inf] <- NA)
```

Comment: To avoid the error, you can convert `x` to vector within the function first and then return `as.xts`: `out <- ave(x, as.Date(index(x)), FUN= function(x) {xv <- as.vector(x);as.xts(ifelse(xv == -Inf,NA,xv),index(x))})`. Note also use of `ifelse` to do the conversion from `-Inf` to `NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to group by day here since the computation is done element by element anyways:

```
replace(x, x == -Inf, NA)
```

or if overwriting is ok then:

```
x[x == -Inf] <- NA
```

If your actual function does make use of grouping and this was just an example then apply `ave` to `coredata(x)` so that we are dealing with plain vectors and be sure that the function applied actually returns the result (which in the question it does not):

```
fun <- function(x) replace(x, x == -Inf, NA)
x[] <- ave(coredata(x), as.Date(index(x)), FUN = fun)
```

We could also consider using `!is.finite(x)` for the test.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are fine, but you can alternatively easily and succinctly achieve averaging (or any reasonable function) in time intervals (hour, day week etc) easily using `xts` tools (converting `zoo` to `xts`).  Are you aware of `?period.apply`, and its wrapper function `apply.daily`?

```
# Solve your overall problem in one line with no error generated when Inf values included:
x.daily <- apply.daily(x, mean, na.rm = T)

# > x.daily
# [,1]
# 2010-01-05 00:20:00 -Inf
# 2010-01-06 00:08:00  NaN

# Solve your first problem compactly (Replace +-Inf values in column 1 (generalise to any column number) of `x` with NA):
x[!is.finite(x[, 1]) &!is.na(x[, 1]), 1] <- NA

# Solve your second problem compactly (average by day):
x.daily <- apply.daily(x, FUN = mean, na.rm = T)

#Optional: tidy up timestamps in x.daily for equal spaced alignment in YYMMDD HHMMSS (NB HHMMSS will vary depending on your timezone.  Should align for 86400 to 00:00:00 equivalent in UTC):
x.daily <- align.time(x.daily, 86400)
# > x.daily
# [,1]
# 2010-01-05 19:00:00    2
# 2010-01-06 19:00:00  NaN
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the `period.apply` function, but there is an issue with using them with the na.locf function as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184867/copy-down-last-value-over-a-daily-period) S.O post, so I am using the ave function instead.

Comment: That "issue" is easily avoided if you use `split(..., "days"))`, then `lapply` with the aggregation you want (`mean` here) and then rbind the results.